# is it possible, in an embedded system, to read the expire date of a tls certificate?

Tags: ssl, embedded

I have an embedded system who connects to a site using tls.
Is it possible, in an embedded system, to read the expire date of a tls certificate?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a functional TLS client that is able to connect to a site secured using TLS, this is likely that some function in the API of the library supporting this feature would allow you to access and parse the X.509 certificate the server sent to the client during the "Server Hello" - see for example [this article](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=ssl-overview-tls-handshake) for more details on the TLS handshake. The first step would be to identify which one your system is using. A candidate would be for example be [mbedtls](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls).